# how to check if a record implements a particular protocol?

Tags: clojure

I have a protocol:

```
(defprotocol IInterval
  (-duration  [in]))
```

and a record that implements it:

```
(defrecord Interval [start end]
  IInterval
  (-duration  [_] (- end
                     start)))
```

if I create `(def i1 (Interval 0 1000))`

how would I be able to the method `implements?` where:

```
(implements? IInterval i1) => true
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `satisfies?`:

```
(satisfies? IInterval i1)
```

Comment: @zcaudate why not? That is exactly what the function does: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/satisfies_q

Comment: I thought it worked... but it only works for extend-protocol, not for how I defined the record in my question.

Comment: @johnbakers... you can try it out like I did

Comment: @zcaudate - I spelled the protocol name wrongly. The code in your question results in `(satisfies? IInterval (->Interval 0 1000))` to return `true` for me.

Comment: @Lee.... hmmm... you're right.... it works when I put them it the same file but somehow when I have them in seperate files it doesn't work.... sorry about the mixup. I'll had to do more investigating as to what happened

Comment: @zcaudate - Are you `require`ing the implementing namespace anywhere? The protocol implementation will not be added unless the namespace is evaluated.

Comment: @Lee - I have defined it here https://github.com/zcaudate/hara/blob/master/src/hara/time.clj#L70 and my test fails here: https://github.com/zcaudate/hara/blob/master/test/hara/time_test.clj#L31 it's not a big deal but still curious as to why it's failing